# Configuring HTTPS for Local ELK Stack with Nginx Reverse Proxy

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, nginx, ssl, proxy

I have set up an ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana) stack using Docker Compose, and everything is working as expected over HTTP. I can access my Kibana interface via a local OAuth2-proxy at `localhost:4180` which redirects to an authentication page. After successful authentication, I'm directed to the Kibana dashboard.

For development purposes, I wanted to shift this setup to HTTPS. I've created a self-signed certificate and managed to serve a static `index.html` page on `https://localhost` using the following nginx config:

```
server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

However, I'm struggling to do the same for the entire ELK stack, especially considering the reverse proxy setup I have.

Here are the relevant parts of my setup:

**Docker Compose Configuration:**

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:

  # The 'setup' service runs a one-off script which initializes users inside
  # Elasticsearch — such as 'logstash_internal' and 'kibana_system' — with the
  # values of the passwords defined in the '.env' file. It also creates the
  # roles required by some of these users.
  #
  # This task only needs to be performed once, during the *initial* startup of
  # the stack. Any subsequent run will reset the passwords of existing users to
  # the values defined inside the '.env' file, and the built-in roles to their
  # default permissions.
  #
  # By default, it is excluded from the services started by 'docker compose up'
  # due to the non-default profile it belongs to. To run it, either provide the
  # '--profile=setup' CLI flag to Compose commands, or "up" the service by name
  # such as 'docker compose up setup'.
  setup:
    profiles:
      - setup
    build:
      context: setup/
      args:
        ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
    init: true
    volumes:
      - ./setup/entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh:ro,Z
      - ./setup/lib.sh:/lib.sh:ro,Z
      - ./setup/roles:/roles:ro,Z
    environment:
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD:-}
      LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
      KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD: ${KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD:-}
      METRICBEAT_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${METRICBEAT_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
      FILEBEAT_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${FILEBEAT_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
      HEARTBEAT_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${HEARTBEAT_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
      MONITORING_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${MONITORING_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
      BEATS_SYSTEM_PASSWORD: ${BEATS_SYSTEM_PASSWORD:-}
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml:ro,Z
      - elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:Z
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
      - 9300:9300
    environment:
      node.name: elasticsearch
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms512m -Xmx512m
      # Bootstrap password.
      # Used to initialize the keystore during the initial startup of
      # Elasticsearch. Ignored on subsequent runs.
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: ${ELASTIC_PASSWORD:-}
      # Use single node discovery in order to disable production mode and avoid bootstrap checks.
      # see: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html
      discovery.type: single-node
    networks:
      - elk
    restart: unless-stopped

  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro,Z
      - ./logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline:ro,Z
    ports:
      - 5044:5044
      - 50000:50000/tcp
      - 50000:50000/udp
      - 9600:9600
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: -Xms256m -Xmx256m
      LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD: ${LOGSTASH_INTERNAL_PASSWORD:-}
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    restart: unless-stopped

  kibana:
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELASTIC_VERSION: ${ELASTIC_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ./kibana/config/kibana.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml:ro,Z
    ports:
      - 5601:5601
    environment:
      KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD: ${KIBANA_SYSTEM_PASSWORD:-}
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    restart: unless-stopped

  oauth2-proxy:
    build: ./oauth2_proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "4180:4180"
    links:
      - nginx-proxy
    networks:
      - elk
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./certs 
        target: /etc/ssl/certs
      # mount valid_emails file from host path
      # - ${PWD}/valid_emails:/usr/valid_emails
    environment:
 ** here are my passwords and env vars needed for oauth2-proxy to run**


  nginx-proxy:
    volumes:
    - type: bind
      source: ./certs 
      target: /etc/ssl/certs
    networks:
      - elk
    build: ./nginx_proxy
    links:
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
      - kibana
    environment:
      - NGINX_PORT=8080
      - DIGEST=SECRET
      - DOLLAR=$$
      - BASE_PATH=/
    command: /bin/bash -c "envsubst < /etc/nginx/nginx-template.conf > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    restart: always

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

**Nginx Configuration (nginx.config):**

```
nginx.config:
http {
    server {
        listen ${NGINX_PORT};
        server_name localhost;

        location ${BASE_PATH} {
            # pass request (dst BASE_PATH) to kibana
            proxy_pass http://kibana:5601/;
            # basic auth
            proxy_set_header Authorization "Basic ${DIGEST}";

            proxy_set_header es-security-runas-user ${DOLLAR}http_x_forwarded_user;
            proxy_set_header x-proxy-user ${DOLLAR}http_x_forwarded_user;

            rewrite /login http://localhost:4180/oauth2/sign_in redirect;
        }
    }
}

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
```

**Start Script (start.sh):**

```bash
oauth2_proxy \
 --email-domain=* \
 --upstream=$UPSTREAM \
 --http-address=$HTTP_ADDRESS \
 --redirect-url=$REDIRECT_URL \
 --cookie-secret=$COOKIE_SECRET \
 --tls-cert-file=/etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt \
 --tls-key-file=/etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key \
 --cookie-name=$COOKIE_NAME \
 --cookie-secure=$COOKIE_SECURE \
 --provider=$PROVIDER \
 --client-id=$CLIENT_ID \
 --client-secret=$CLIENT_SECRET
```

I haven't included all project files due to its size, but everything functions locally; I just need guidance on configuring the stack to operate over HTTPS with an Nginx reverse proxy.

I am not certain about the changes needed to integrate HTTPS throughout the stack, especially considering the OAuth2-proxy and Nginx reverse proxy. Could someone guide me on this?